# Referring to programmatically created UI elements in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, xamarin

I was wondering how to refer to an View if I create it programmatically.

I have to create new passenger Views with "Add Passenger" and respectively "Remove Passenger" buttons to my app. The promts are kept LinearLayouts called "@+id/passenger" which have two EditTexts called "@+id/passenger_name" and "@+id/passenger_weight". Those are then kept in a yet another parent LinearLayout called passenger_layout that can hold all the passenger LinearLayouts in a bunch

Adding new passengers is easy, but I have no idea how to refer to the newly created elements. I guess they get a identifier of some sort automatically? I'd prefer them to be "passenger_name%" and "passenger_weight%", where % is an index _passengerCount.

```
addPassenger.Click += delegate {
            //Add to index
            ++passengerCount;
            //Prep new passenger layout
            var newLayout = new LinearLayout(Activity);
            //Set LayoutParameters from the existing passenger LayoutParameters
            newLayout.LayoutParameters = newPassenger.LayoutParameters;

            //Prep the new EditTexts
            var name = new EditText(Activity);
            var weight = new EditText(Activity);

            //Set the EditTexts' LayoutParameters from existing LayoutParameters
            name.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(passengerName.LayoutParameters);
            weight.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(passengerWeight.LayoutParameters);

            //These cleary don't work :<
//              name.Id = Resources.GetIdentifier( "passenger_name" + passengerCount, "id", Activity.PackageName);
//              weight.Id = "passenger_weight" + passengerCount;


            //Add EditTexts to the new passenger layout and then and then add the new passenger to the parent LinearLayout 
            newLayout.AddView(name);
            newLayout.AddView(weight);
            passengerLayout.AddView(newLayout);
            Log.Debug(GetType().FullName, "Add clicked");
        };
```

That is my click delegate to create a new passenger, but again even if I create them like this I don't know how I can find them later if I have to for example remove them or get the name or weight data.

How do I refer to programmatically created UI elements?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a view, try giving it some ID, and holding that ID as a static reference somewhere.

Then, you could simply call the containing view's findViewById(MY_VIEWS_ID) and get the view.

Of course, alternatively, you could always hold a reference to the view you created somewhere in your code when you create it. If you're afraid of memory leaks, you could use WeakReference.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a static variable within the Activity that will contain the UI element after it gets initialized.

Something like:

```
// Definition
private static TextView textViewToSave = null;

textViewToSave = // create the TextView programatically.

// Do stuff with the saved TextView
textViewToSave.setText("O Hai world!");
```

Comment: But wouldn't I then have to have a bunch of variables ready? I guess the passenger count might go as high as 10 or 15 so it seems to be a bit unconventional way to deal with it. I guess this is an crude way to do it which is okay by me at the moment...

Comment: You could create a `HashMap` instead to keep your list of UI elements and maybe keep any special data you require as the value. Or you could create a class for it if you need more than one property to maintain and initialize that class as a `List` or `ArrayList`.